# Lurching vs careening vs swerving

Tags: meaning

I'm hoping to be enlightened on the nuances between these three words: **lurching**, **careening**, and **swerving**.

I'm particularly confused about the distinction between *lurching* and *careening*. They're both used to describe vehicles that are driving in some dangerous configuration but that's where my imagination stops.

From Oxford Languages:

Lurch : make an abrupt, unsteady, uncontrolled movement or series of movements; stagger.

Careen : move swiftly and in an uncontrolled way.

Swerve: change or cause to change direction abruptly.

Comment: What definitions have you looked up to these words that contribute to your confusion?

Comment: If you're going to compare those verbs, might as well also consider "career", defined by Chambers as "to gallop; to rush wildly; to move or run rapidly".

Comment: Careening is mainly American.

Comment: Lurching is unrelated to the others, describing a sudden forward lunge. The others are the bad curvy movements of driving and not staying in your lane.

Comment: Well, if you're an Adams Family monster then you're likely "lurching".

Comment: @Yosef Baskin Mirriam-Webster says that a ship can *lurch* on its side.

Comment: I’d characterize lurching as sporadic changes in acceleration and careening as inadequate (or dangerous) changes in lateral acceleration, and swerving as making necessary changes in lateral acceleration.

Comment: The definitions the OP cites seem clear enough: careening is fast movement, swerving involves changes of direction as you travel, and lurch means abrupt movements without necessarily speed or continued motion.

Comment: @Stuart F but the definitions vary according to the source. You can scour the comments on this post alone to see the diversity of non-equivalent answers.

Answer (score 0):

Lurching would be a fore and aft movement like accelerating and decelerating. Swerving is a side to side movement. Careening has no specific direction implied, it could include all directions at random.

Comment: This answer is inadequate and wrong. You should quote references for your assertions; otherwise they are no use to the questioners. Dictionary definitions do not support this answer. Look at Cambridge dictionary for example. Lurching is not confined to fore and aft but may also be side to side. Careening is going forward and side to side.